# Theme not applying correctly

Tags: debian, gnome, gtk, theme

I just switched from Parabola running GNOME 3.14 to Debian Sid running GNOME 3.14, and the same theme that worked fine on Parabola now isn't applying correctly.

[image: Screenshot]

The scroll bars among other elements are left unthemed. I got the theme from the Arch package obtainable [here](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/community/any/numix-themes/).

I'm not sure why this particular theme is failing to apply everywhere.

This also affects Qt applications such as the Electrum wallet.

[image: Screenshot]

The top of the window looks correct, but the tabs are unthemed.

Comment: Do you have the murrine gtk engine installed? Have you chosen it as the default engine?

Comment: I did not have it installed. How does one change their default engine?

Comment: Not sure, I don't use GNOME. It should be in the settings somewhere. If not, you should be able to install `gnome-tweak-tool` or `gnome-color-chooser` both of which should let you set it. Let me know if that works and I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like an idiot, I didn't look at the dependencies for `numix-themes` on Arch.

I didn't think themes needed other packages.

To resolve the issue:

```
# apt-get install gtk-engines-murrine
```

and restart the shell (I rebooted).

Comment: Ah, cool, so the engine was automatically changed when you installed this?

Comment: Only after rebooting did I see the effect. Don't know if the reboot was required or if all I needed was to restart X11.

Comment: OK. Also, you need to wait 48 hours after posting but if you remember, please take a minute and click the check mark under the vote count to the left, this will [signify to everyone](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) that your issue's been resolved.